# Spring Integration Executor Channel loosing items

Tags: spring-integration, channel

For some reason, the following Executor Channel is only processing 5 items and discarding the rest:

```
<task:executor id="ImportItemExecutor" pool-size="5"/>   
<channel id="ImportItemChannel" datatype="com.processing.data.generic.ImportItem,java.lang.String">
    <dispatcher task-executor="ImportItemExecutor"/> 
</channel>
```

The input looks like this:

```
<!-- Processing: Create IMPORT_SOURCE, prepare file as resource, and let the kernel handle the processing -->
<chain id="ProcessingXmlChain" input-channel="FullEarningsResponseChannel" output-channel="ImportItemChannel">
    [Code shortened]
    <splitter id="FullEarningsSplitter" ref="FullEarningsSplitterBean"/>
</chain>
```

The sole consumer looks like this:

```
<chain id ="ImportItemChain" input-channel="ImportItemChannel" output-channel="ReportedFileChannel">
        <!-- Call the main processing pipeline which returns a Report object as payload -->        
        <gateway request-channel="ResultRouterChannel" error-channel="errorChannel"/>

        <!-- Outgoing payload must be the processed file -->
        <transformer expression="headers.file_xml"/>
</chain>
```

What could be the reason for this strange behaviour?
How can it be fixed?

Comment: Maybe this is also of relevance: In case I'm using a normal Channel, only the first item gets procesed.

Comment: Your `ResultRouterChannel` subflow must return a message, otherwise you thread hangs to wait a `reply` and block thread from thread-pool finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not lost, they are queued - what are the 5 threads doing? Take a thread dump with jstack or VisualVM.

My guess is your gateway is hanging waiting for a reply.

Comment: Seems it really was hanging while waiting for a reply. Replacing the gateway with a bridge solved the problem.